# How to clean a dictionary where the values are equal to a variable

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary composed of multiple key. Is has been created by a loop so the keys generated at the beginning don't have values but, I fill them later.
Sometimes, a key is not filled so I want to remove it from the dictionary

The dictionary look like:

```
{'a' : [1,2,3,4] , 'b' : [5,6,7,8] ,'c': [] ,'d': [9,10,11]}
```

I may have multiple values that look like 'c'
i have tried the try/except but still get the "dictionary changed size during iteration"

```
d= {'a' : [1,2,3,4] , 'b' : [5,6,7,8] ,'c': [] ,'d': [9,10,11]}
dic_key = d.keys()
for key in dic_key:
         try:
             if len(d[key]) == 0:
                    del d[key]
         except:
             pass
```

"dictionary changed size during iteration"

Comment: yup @Sayse, definitely a duplicate of at least the second one

Comment: You shouldn't modify an iterable you're looping through. Either create a second dictionary so you can have one dictionary to iterate over and another to modify, or use a comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

use [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

try this:

```py
d = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if len(v)}
```

Comment: `if v` should be sufficient. no need to check `len`

Comment: you're right, as `bool([]) is False`